# menu in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to make a kind of menu inside a while loop. I wrote this code

```
System.out.println("age , sex or exit" );

BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String r = bufferRead.readLine();
while(!(r.equals("exit")))
{
  if(r.equals("age"))
  {
    System.out.println("enter name");
    r = bufferRead.readLine();
    getAge(r);
    System.out.println("age , sex or exit" );
    r = bufferRead.readLine();
  }

  if(r.equals("sex"))
  {
    System.out.println("enter name");
    r = bufferRead.readLine();
    getSex(r);
    System.out.println("age , sex or exit" );
    r = bufferRead.readLine();
  }
}
```

It works the first time but it don't work properly. Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it don't work properly" [sic]?  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

You're reading the line only once.

Try something in the lines of (pun not intended):

```
String r = null;
while((r = bufferRead.readLine()) != null) {
    // the rest of your while loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is an ideal case for a DO WHILE loop.

```
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String r;

 do {
     System.out.println("age, sex or exit");
     r = bufferRead.readLine();

     switch(r){
        case : age { getAge(r) }
        case : sex { getSex(r) }
      }

    } while(!"exit".equals(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your program, the problem is once you set r and enter the loop it will never let you set it again and so it cannot change and your loop keeps outputting.  If that's right then a possible solution is to set r inside the loop, like so:

```
        String r = "This will change";//Anything other than exit so the loop starts
        while(!(r.equals("exit"))) {//Start loop
             r = bufferRead.readLine();//Now set r
```

By setting r inside your program loops (Or keeps running) until you type exit.